# Remove out of bounds elements in slick-slide carousel

Tags: reactjs, slick.js, react-slick

I use the react-slick carousel, but the next and previous texts stick out. How do I fix this?

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/embed/crimson-microservice-ll0hho?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark